# Will the content in personal chat room be removed sometime?

Tags: support

Will the content in personal chat room (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1395/discussion-between-sheegaon-and-tim) be removed sometime, because if yes, I will make a copy before I leave the room. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person actively talking in the room. A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users.
>
> Rooms not worth retaining which are inactive for 7 days will be deleted. Rooms worth retaining which are inactive for 14 days will be frozen. Frozen rooms do not allow any new messages to be sent, and are not shown in the default room list to prevent cluttering the rooms interface.

http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention